# ios store URL images in offline mode(not connected to internet)

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimage, uibutton, nsurlconnection

I am fetching array of images from different urls..the images are loading perfectly..but if i need to display the images in offline mode..I cant find a right way to get it.Here is my code

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
NSString *arr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSURL URLWithString: 
                                        @"http://images.wikia.com/marvelmovies/images/5/5e/The-hulk-2003.jpg"],
              [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://cdn.gottabemobile.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/ios62.jpg"],
             [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://challenge.roadef.org/2012/img/google_logo.jpg"],
              [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://addyosmani.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/Google-doodle-of-Richard-007.jpg"],
              [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://techcitement.com/admin/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/apple-vs-google_2.jpg"],
              [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.andymangels.com/images/IronMan_9_wallpaper.jpg"],
              [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://sequelnews.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/iphone_5.jpg"],Nil];

NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:arr];

NSData* theData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

int row = 0;
     int column = 0;

     for(int i = 0; i < [(NSArray*) url count]; ++i) {
         UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:(NSURL*)   [(NSArray*)url objectAtIndex:i]]]; 

         UIButton * button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
         button.frame = CGRectMake(column*100+16, row*90, 80, 80);
         [button setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 

         [button addTarget:self 
                    action:@selector(buttonClicked:) 
          forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
         button.tag = i; 
         [self.view addSubview:button];

         if (column == 2) {
             column = 0;
             row++;
         } else {
             column++;
         }
     }      
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *localFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:arr];
[theData writeToFile:localFilePath atomically:YES];

}
```

Guidance please...

Comment: you can cache thos image in caches folder so that you don't need to download those images again and again and when your work with those images is completed then delete those images from cache.

Answer (score 1):

Try [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage), `SDWebImage` can download image and save into disk for cache, that you can use in offline.

Comment: @Dany for crying out loud, just take out the comma at the end and it is fine...I will edit the question

Comment: Just asking google would have gave you this link https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/

Answer (score 0):

You should be saving the images to your device, so you can access them when you're not connected to the internet. The way you do it right now you always load the url.

You can try it like this:
Use a NSData object for every image and load the url content in it.

```
NSData* theData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:yourURLHere];
```

Now you can save this object to your device and access it whenever you need to.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *localFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"picName.jpg"];
[theData writeToFile:localFilePath atomically:YES];
```

And that should be about it

Comment: This is not a good way to do it (the first part), because it is not async for a process that will likely take too much time.