# iOS app additional content download

Tags: ios, download, storage

I have an iOS app which has a lot of images and sounds in it, hence the build size is growing rapidly and can no longer fit in the 50MB limit for 3G download. I would like to upload those images and sounds to an online server and download them from the application on demand. Can anyone please recommend some online storage (for example Amazon S3) and give suggestions for best practices about this issue?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I upload my files to an "unlimited site" with Network solutions, however if you don't want to pay for anything like this just upload the photos to photo bucket or something and right click on them and click "Get image address" then use this URL to download the images to your app. (Check to make sure it doesn't violate their terms of use though, I don't know if it does or not!)

As for best practices, I probably use the absolute worst method which is displaying it in a UIWebView off-screen and taking a picture of it using CoreGraphics then saving that picture haha! I'll leave you with this link for a probably better solution to your second half of the question, that being "Best practices": [ios store URL images in offline mode(not connected to internet)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11574403/ios-store-url-images-in-offline-modenot-connected-to-internet)